# How do I solve this CSV reader problem in python?

Tags: python, csv, reader

I'm trying to read a CSV file into python and I looked at different tutorials for it.

Input:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvdatei:
    csv_reader=csv.reader('test.csv')    
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
['t']
['e']
['s']
['t']
['.']
['c']
['s']
['v']
```

Why does this not work? Why does it give me the split up file name as output?

I use python 3.7.3 on Spyder.

Comment: csv.reader(csvdatei) perhaps? https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to give `csv` the contents of the file and not the filename:

```py
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvdatei:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvdatei)    
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```